# jquery modal call to another function, open on call from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all anyone know what I might be missing in order to make this pop up modal open?  I want vendor_accept_modal function to open the modal when called from the function `other`.

```
function other(){
//do stuff here;
vendor_accept_modal();
}


function vendor_accept_modal() {
        var popup_name = jQuery(this).attr('popup-open');
 jQuery('[popup-name="' + popup_name + '"]').fadeIn(300);
}
```

Currently I have double checked that the call to the function is good by adding in an alert to prove it. It is a good call to the function, its just that the modal doesnt open with the code above
html is

```
<a class="open-button" popup-open="popup-1" href="javascript:void(0)"> Popup 
        Preview</a>
         
        <div class="popup" popup-name="popup-1">
            <div class="popup-content">
            <h2>Model </h2>
        <p>Model content will be here.</p>
        <a class="close-button" popup-close="popup-1" href="javascript:void(0)">x</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function vendor_accept_modal() {
        var popup_name = jQuery(this).attr('popup-open');
 jQuery('[popup-name="' + popup_name + '"]').fadeIn(300);
}
```

```html
<a class="open-button" popup-open="popup-1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="vendor_accept_model()"> Popup 
        Preview</a>
         
        <div class="popup" popup-name="popup-1">
            <div class="popup-content">
            <h2>Model </h2>
        <p>Model content will be here.</p>
        <a class="close-button" popup-close="popup-1" href="javascript:void(0)">x</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You have to use onclick event in a tag.

Comment: Thank you. No better way without the html onclick tag to run simply by calling the function itself from another function?

Comment: Sorry I don`t know any other way. Hope you find one. Anyway can you vote me?